# ServletServerContainerFactoryBean Stomp mode is invalid

Tags: spring, stomp

The tomcat web container websocket buffer size limit is 8kb, Use ServletServerContainerFactoryBean can be adjusted to 64kb. But it does not support Stomp. I have searched various materials to modify the limit, but all failed. Please give me some guidance, thank you!

```java
@Configuration
public class MyServerContainerConfigurer{
      @Bean
      public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
            ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
            container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(64*1024);
            container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(64*1024);
            return container;
      }
}
```

Effective in normal mode, as shown in the following example.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class MyWebSocketConfigurer implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new TextWebSocketHandler(),"/endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

It is invalid in Stomp mode, Example of Stomp.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class MyWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher("."));
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }


    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration webSocketTransportRegistration) {
        webSocketTransportRegistration
                .setMessageSizeLimit(1024 * 1024)
                .setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024 );

    }


}
```

Error log

```
2020-06-16 13:45:51.226 DEBUG 11628 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.h.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator : StandardWebSocketSession[id=c11461a9-8340-e006-dda9-cf50716694dd, uri=ws://localhost:8080/portfolio] closed with CloseStatus[code=1009, reason=No async message support and buffer too small. Buffer size: [8,192], Message size: [11,020]]
```

---

SpringBoot  Version : 2.3.0